# Wordpress htaccess change root for spa

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, nuxt.js, single-page-application

My thoughts:

Client via SPA (Nuxt; static)
Apache Server with Wordpress (headless)

I want to change the htaccess file from wordpress. I need to rewrite the /wp-admin, /wp-json s.o. as normally way. Wordpress should redirect this requests normally (wordpress like). But, all other requests should executed in a different document root where the nuxt app lies.

Is it possible, what can i do? Thx.

I tried this htaccess. But it doesn't work for me:

````
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
#RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^MYURL$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wp-content/themes/gzz/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wp-json
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wp-admin
RewriteRule (.*) /wp-content/themes/gzz/$1 [L]

#RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /wp-json [OR]#
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-login\.php(.*)$ [OR]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-admin$
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>```
````